# Angular routing with ng-view is not working

Tags: angularjs, routes, partial-views

I don't understand why I can't get this to work.

I'll share the relevant code, let me know if you need to see more stuff.

**Index.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3"><a href="#/liberals">Liberals</a></div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when("/liberals", {
        templateUrl: "partials/liberals.html"
        , controller: "LiberalsController"
    });
});

app.controller('LiberalsController', function ($scope, $http) {
    var url = "workingURL"; /// changed function to a simple string message to test
    $scope.message = "Hello Liberals";
});
```

**(partial view) liberals.html**

```
    <h1>Hello</h1> 
     {{message}}
```

PS: I'm not working on a political hate website for or against liberals!

Comment: what display in console??

Comment: Do you get any error message when the link is clicked?

Comment: the console is empty, and I get no error messages when I click the link

Comment: I've loaded the angular.js and angular.route.js, if that's what you're asking(?)

Comment: Josem, what version are u using ? 1.6+ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of AngularJS 1.6, the default value of the `hashPrefix` has been changed to `!`.

There's two ways to get your routing to work with AngularJS 1.6+:

- Add the hashprefix (`!`) to your `href`'s:

`<a href="#!/liberals">Liberals</a>`

- Change (remove) the `hashPrefix` value using `$locationProvider`:

`$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`

I've created a working plunkr in which I used the second approach:
https://plnkr.co/edit/oTB6OMNNe8kF5Drl75Wn?p=preview

The commit regarding this breaking change can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52)

Comment: There it is! Thank you so very much!

Comment: I am facing same issue but not working !! Is there any version issue I need to correct ?

Comment: That's hard to tell. Create a plunkr and ping me at https://gitter.im/angular/angular.js so I can take a look at it.