# AngularJS NgRoute - Url Changes But view doesnt render,No errors

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

appscript.js

```
    var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);


    myApp.config([$routeProvider,function($routeProvider) {

      $routeProvider

      // route for the home page
        .when('/home', {

        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
      })

      // route for the about page
      .when('/services', {
        templateUrl: 'services.html',
        controller: 'servicesController'
      })

      // route for the contact page
      .when('/contacts', {
        templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
        controller: 'contactsController'
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/services' });
    }
    ]);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head >


    <script src="appscript.js"></script>

    <link href="Styles/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="homeController.js"></script>    
      <script src="servicesController.js"></script>
       <script src="contactsController.js"></script>
       <script src="aboutController.js"></script>
       <script src="clientsController.js"></script>

       <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body >
<div class="header" > <h2 style="color:blue;">Training Institute</h2> 
  </div>
<div class="nav">

<a href="#/home">Home</a>
<a href="#/about">About</a>
  <a href="#/services">Services</a>
  <a href="#/clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#/contacts">Contact</a>

  </div>

<div class="content"  >  
<ng-view>   </ng-view>

  </div>

<div class="footer">footer</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

homeController.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('homeController',function($scope)
        {

           $scope.message="i am in home controller";

        }


);
```

home.html

```
<div>i am in home partial template</div>
```

I have searched related questions and did many changes but still not able to load partial templates in the view.The url is changed but the veiw doesnt update.

I put all my code files in the same location where index.html is there,to make sure the issue is not because of incorrect paths.

Comment: What version of angularjs are u using?

Comment: i refered v1.6.3 in the appscript.js file

Comment: try reordering the scripts called in the head tag like this .. angular.min --> angular-route --> appscript --> controllers

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816212/angular-routing-with-ng-view-is-not-working/42816780#42816780 which I answered. Could you check the answer provided over there ?

Comment: @ModarNa i tried re ordering ,it fixed the issue of controller message displaying ,but not template loading.

Comment: @FrederikPrijck it did not  worked!

Comment: Sorry for stupid question .. but what errors are you getting in console after reordering...

Comment: @ModarNa actually i am not getting any errors,just that view is not updated.

Comment: When you start the project what is the url ?

Comment: Is it #/index  or #/services

Comment: when loaded the url is index.html after click on home link it changed to index.html#!#%2Fhome ,but when mousehover the home link the url is shown as #/home ,not sure y the url is changed to #!#%2Fhome after click on home link

Comment: @vamshi If you are using angularjs 1.6, you should either change the `hashPrefix` or either use the hasPrefix in `href`'s. You also need to load `angular-route.js` AFTER `angular.js` instead of before, and then load your own scripts (as mentioned by Modar Na).

Comment: @FrederikPrijck i tried both but didn't worked.

Comment: here's your code, working perfectly: https://plnkr.co/edit/oTB6OMNNe8kF5Drl75Wn?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a plunkr to reproduce and fix your problem which you can find here: https://plnkr.co/edit/oTB6OMNNe8kF5Drl75Wn?p=preview (note: only home, services and contacts work, as those are the only routes configures in ur code so the rest falls back to the route specified in `otherwise`)

There are two issues with your code:

- You're order of files is incorrect, it needs to be:

  ```
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="appscript.js"></script>
  <script src="homeController.js"></script>    
  <script src="servicesController.js"></script>
  <script src="contactsController.js"></script>
  <script src="aboutController.js"></script>
  <script src="clientsController.js"></script>
  ```
- You're using AngularJS 1.6, in order to use routing ensure to read my answer here: [Angular routing with ng-view is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816212/angular-routing-with-ng-view-is-not-working/42816780#42816780)

Long story short: As of AngularJS 1.6, the default value for `hashPrefix` is `!`. As you're not making use of it, you either have to use it or reset it to `''` using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')`. This change was introduced as of AngularJS 1.6 due this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52

Note: If this still doesn't help you, we might need more information as we have no idea what the content of all those js files are. Feel free to update my plunkr to reproduce your problem in that case.

Comment: i updated the plunkr,please take a look ,its still not updating the view https://plnkr.co/edit/dkckKg0njxd7JSdxPGXq?p=options

Comment: Your plunkr has mulitple errors:

You need to change `myApp.config([$routeProvider,function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {` to `myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {`. Then you need to ensure `servicesController`and `contactsController` exists.

Comment: Awesome..its working!!Thanks! but i have seen many posts with the same syntax as below myApp.config([$routeProvider,function($routeProvider) {   ,how did it worked for others??

Comment: The array has to contain strings, and the last argument is the function. You're passing `$routeProvider` as the first parameter, but you need it to be `'$routeProvider'`. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: eclipse doesnt show any errors ..do you know how to make eclipse show errors like these?

Comment: Can you mark my answer as an answer if it helped you? This would be beneficial for future developers reading this question.